# Trouble compiling C/C++ project in NetBeans 6.8 with MinGW on Windows

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, linker

I am learning C and because VC++ 2008 doesn't support C99 features I have just installed NetBeans and configure it to work with MinGW. I can compile single file project ( main.c) and use debugger but when I add new file to project I get error "undefined reference to  ...  function(code) in that file..". Obviously MinGW does't link my files or I don't know how properly add them to my project (c standard library files work fine).

```
/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/don/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_7'
/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_7.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/don/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_7'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
gcc.exe     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_7 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o  
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/don/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_7/main.c:5: undefined reference to `X'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_7.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/don/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_7'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/don/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_7'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

main.c

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    X();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H
#define _HEADER_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void X(void);

#endif
```

source.c

```
#include "header.h"
void X(void)
{
    printf("dsfdas");
}
```

Comment: We need the exact error message and the code the compiler's complaining about before we'll be much help. It should be noted that MinGW is missing support for several large pieces of the Windows API. Perhaps that's the issue you're running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. I was adding files in physical view not while I am in logical view.

Comment: I have the same error, but I didn't understand your solution, can you explain more please.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your include guards

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H //These
#define _HEADER_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void X(void);

#endif
```

Names beginning with an underscore (_) are reserved for use by the C and C++ standard libraries. It's entirely possible _HEADER_H is already defined somewhere, which would make `main.c` not compile.

Comment: That's not the issue. When I have for example main.c file and source.c file, and I include source.c in main.c everything works. But when I have main.c->include->header.h and source.c->include header.h I get error "undefined reference to function `X'"